# Chartjs - how to make line position to vertical center and how to display dotted sharp in the backround?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I would like to ask how to configure chart using Chartjs library to get result similar like on the image below in the right way? I tried to find any option in the documentation http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options, but without luck.

[image]

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js version 2+

Use the **borderDash** property in scales.x|yAxes.gridLines configuration object.

- http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#grid-line-configuration

Example :

- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzazda?editors=0010#0

---

```
var options = {
    scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                   gridLines: {
                      display: true,
                      lineWidth: 1,
                      borderDash: [1, 2],
                      color: "black"
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                   gridLines: {
                      display: true,
                      lineWidth: 1,
                      borderDash: [1, 2],
                      color: "black"
                    }
                }],
            }
}
```